# How to push a local video when there are no livestream

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I'm actually looking to a ningx rtmp server which send video flux to Twitch.

But (obviously there is a but) , i'm looking to have a server which do the following :

If no one send a flux with OBS or XSplit, the server send a local video to Twich
If someone send a flux, the server switch to this flux whitout being deconnected on Twitch
The server switch again to the local video when the flux get stopped.
I think there is some issue with on_play or on_connect but i'm not sure about how it's works.
If anybody have any idea, it could be great.

P.S : Actually, it's possible to have little delay offline between the switch because it could be possible to have a computer which take the flux from the server then send it to Twitch, so I'll juste have few seconds black screen I guess.

Comment: what is a flux?

Comment: By flux i mean the video that someone push on the server with OBS for example.